# Solving $2|x+1|>|x+4|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

I'm trying to solve the following equations and inequalities for $x\in\mathbb R$:

$$2|x+1|>|x+4|$$

I know I'm supposed to consider the intervals $(-\infty,-4), [-4,-1]$ and $(-1,\infty)$ but don't know how each affects the equation and how to conclude a result.

I think considering interval $(-\infty,-4)$: $2|1+x|>|4+x|$ $\Rightarrow x>2$ but if I'm right how will it work for the other intervals?

Comment: The point of considering the intervals is so that you can get rid of the absolute value signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
&4(x+1)^2>(x+4)^2\\
&4x^2+8x+4>x^2+8x+16\\
&3x^2-12>0\\
&x>2\ \text{ or }\ x<-2
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

What is the sign of $x+1$ and $x+4$ in each interval?

Then use $|y|=y$ if $y\geq 0$, and $|y|=-y$ if $y\leq 0$.

For instance, if $x\in [-4,-1]$, you have $x+4\geq 0$ so $|x+4|=x+4$ and $x+1\leq 0$ so $|x+1|=-x-1$. In this interval:
$$
2|x+1|>|x+4|\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad 2(-x-1)>x+4\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad 3x<-6\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad x<-2.
$$
So this yields $[-4,-2)$.

Repeat the procedure on the other intervals.

**Alternative**: draw simultaneously the graphs of $2|x+1|$ and $|x+4|$. Then find where the former is above the latter. It is very easy. You just have to find the two intersections.

See [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eonpnullaz).

Comment: I understand they meet at 2 and -2 but can anyone explain how I actually used the method in the question (a practical example would be nice) I still don't understand how to use that method

Comment: @RickyRozay I'veexpanded, see the edit.

Comment: sorry to sound stupid but how do you know $x+4\geq 0$ and $x+1\leq 0$

Comment: If $-4\leq x\leq -1$ then the lhs yields $0\leq x+4$ and the rhs gives $x+1\leq 0$.

Comment: @RickyRozay Do you get it now or do you need other explanations?

Answer (score 1):

The considered intervals are right, use the definition of the absolute value 
$$|x|=\left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
x & x\geq 0 \\
-x & x < 0 \\ 
\end{array}\right.
$$ 
In the Intervalls you can always think which one is the case and so eliminate the absolut value.

To check your results here is a plot, the red one is $2\cdot |x+1|$
[image]

For $x \in (-4,-1)$ we have $x+4 >0$ and $x+1<0$

So the inequality is 
\begin{align*}
2 |x+1| & > |x+4| \\
-2\cdot  (x+1) &> x+4 \\
\iff -2-2x &> x+4 \\
\iff   -6 &> 3 x \\
\iff -2 &> x
\end{align*}

Comment: I understand they meet at 2 and -2 but can anyone explain how I actually used the method in the question (a practical example would be nice) I still don't understand how to use that method :(

Comment: @RickyRozay added the part for $(-4,-1)$

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Our answers could difficultly be more similar...

Comment: @julien indeed what shall we do now ?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Nothing, I guess. It happens all the time.

Comment: how do you know $x+4> 0$ and $x+1< 0$

Comment: i say $x \in (-4,-1)$ so $-4 < x < -1$

Comment: @Julien still your answer got an upvote and mine not

Comment: You should have noticed by now that votes are fairly irrational around here...